# How do i hide the bug image once its hit by a bullet in opengl and c++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am working on defender/space invaders game.

I have drawn bug sprite and a bullet sprite. I shoot at the bug with a bullet but when the bullet hits the bug it draws a collision sprite which stays on the screen. I want the collision sprite to not be drawn after it is drawn. I am using a boolean to determine what sprite is to be drawn.

here is my code.

```
void renderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawShip();
    drawBullet();
    coll_ship_one();
    if (coll == false)
    {
    drawBug_one();
    }
    if (coll == true)
    {
    drawCollision_one();
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: What does the class that represents your bug sprite look like? Do you have a vector of sprites?

Comment: no vector of sprites yet

Comment: That is probably what you need to work on. After you get them in a vector removing and adding becomes easy.

Comment: I am trying to get the collision code to work first.

Comment: You want 3 states (bug, collision, no bug) but your `coll` can hold just two (bug, collision) I would have list of bugs and list of collisions and once bug hit remove it from list and add it to list of collisions ... then each collision should have counter how many frames it should be drawn which will be decremented each frame and once reached zero remove it from list ... another option is to change your `coll` into integer where `0` means no bug `-1`  means bug and any number above `0` means collision (the count of frames to render) this way you can have static arrays instead of dynamic list

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a 3-state bug drawing system, I have used -1 for drawing a bug and 1 for the collision sprite and 0 for not drawing a bug. here is code

```
void renderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawShip();
    drawBullet();
    coll_ship_one();
    if (coll == -1)
    {
    drawBug_one();
    }
    if (coll == 1)
    {
    drawCollision_one();
    coll = 0;
    }
    if (coll == 0)
    {
    // no bug
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```